# Cómo hago para que este arreglo de números me imprima el cuadrado de ellos?

Tags: java, array

He intentado todas las maneras pero no logro que me imprima el cuadrado de los números de mi arreglo. Alguien me puede decir en qué estoy fallando?

```
public class CuadradoArreglo {

    static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    static PrintStream out = System.out;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    double numerosA[] = new double[5];
    double numerosB[] = new double[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < numerosA.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Ingrese los números del arreglo: ");
        numerosA[i] = entrada.nextInt();

    }
    System.out.print("Los números del arreglo son:" + (numerosA));
    System.out.print("Los números ingresados al cuadrado del arreglo son: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numerosB.length; i++) {
        double numerosB[i] = (numbersA.length) * (numbersA.length);
        System.out.print(numerosB);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: creo que el fallo está en que intentas convertir los resultados en Strings, al hacer eso no se calcula bien, es decir, si fuera una suma por ejemplo, pues en vez de sumar 2+2, lo que hace es que el resultado te lo devuelve como 22. También podrías probar el método public static pow(double a, double b) de la clase Math. Espero que te sirva de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: Traté de quitar todos los Strings pero creo que no logré llegar a lo que tengo que hacer. Acabo de corregir mi código, me podrías decir dónde está mi error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Alguien me puede decir en qué estoy fallando?

El programa tiene varios errores de compilación.

**1:** Estás declarando de nuevo el arreglo `numerosB` cuando en realidad ya fue declarado.

```
double numerosB[i] = (numbersA.length) * (numbersA.length);
```

**Solución (quitar el tipo de dato `double`):**

```
numerosB[i] = (numbersA.length) * (numbersA.length);
```

**2.** Aunque hemos arreglado el primer problema, habrá otro error de compilación porqué el identificador `numbersA` en ningún momento fue declarado, es decir, el compilador nunca lo tomará en cuenta porqué no existe. En este caso se debería usar el identificador `numerosA`, debido a que ya se lo declaró anteriormente.

**Solución (reemplazar el identificador `numbersA` por `numerosA`):**

```
numerosB[i] = (numerosA.length) * (numerosA.length);
```

Entonces, con esto no debería dar ningún error de compilación; sin embargo, habrá un error lógico en esta parte del código corregido:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numerosB.length; i++) 
{
     numerosB[i] = (numerosA.length) *(numerosA.length);   
     System.out.print(Arrays.toString(numerosB));
}
```

Si te puedes dar cuenta, ese código estaría multiplicando la longitud/tamaño del vector (en este caso `5`), es decir, el arreglo `numerosB` siempre tendrá guardado un número `25`.

La lógica nos dice que el resultado que debe guardar en el vector `numerosB` es el cuadrado del elemento que tenga el vector `numerosA`, por lo tanto, para arreglar ese error lógico, deberíamos reemplazar el código de arriba por este:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numerosB.length; i++) 
{
    //Se guarda en el vector B el cuadrado del elemento que se tenga en el vector A
    numerosB[i] = (numerosA[i]) * (numerosA[i]);
}
//Por último imprimimos el contenido del vector B (esto no debería ir adentro del bucle, sino afuera)
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(numerosB));
```

Y con esto, hemos solucionado los dos errores de sintaxis y el error lógico.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, agregué todas tus correcciones y además logré hacer que el código me quedará más organizado agregándole unos println. Siempre me salvas, deberías de ser profesor porque explicas demasiado bien!